# Can I link a variable to File Opened Event in tasker?

Tags: tasker, files, search

I want to link a variable to the File Opened event in tasker.
But I can't...Is there any other way to check which file or folder is opened right now...but this event profile is only allowing me to review only one folder which I have selected.I want to assign a variable here...instead of a single folder name like Download

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While this is a known limitation in Tasker there is a workaround which involves creating several events then combining them into a profile through a variable (Profiles Active)

Here is how to go about it:

Lets say you want a "File Opened Event" involving 3 seperate files,  in this case I named them A.csv ; B.csv; and C.scv

[image: 3 files]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Event A

Go to Profile >> Event >> File Opened >> Choose A.csv (Give the Profile a name e.g FOa)

[image: A]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

**Task**

As you know you can't create a profile without a linking task so here is a workaround:

When it asks for the task:

Go to New Task + >>Don't write anything in New task name ( so as to keep it anonymous)

A1 Task >> Wait >> 2 seconds (Note: This is a dummy task and it won't affect anything)

[image: Dummy]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Event B

Go to Profile >> Event >> File File Opened >> Choose B.csv (Give the Profile a name e.g FOb)

**Task**

When it asks for the task:

Go to New Task + >>Don't write anything in New task name ( so as to keep it anonymous)

A1 Task >> Wait >> 2 seconds

Event C

Go to Profile >> Event >> File File Opened >> Choose C.csv  (Give the Profile a name e.g FOc)

**Task**

When it asks for the task:

Go to New Task + >> Don't write anything in New task name ( so as to keep it anonymous)

A1 Task >> Wait >> 2 seconds

**Now to create one profile which accesses all those 3 files as if its one Event proceed as follows...**

Under Profiles tab: Select State >> Variables >> Variable Value >> %PACTIVE ~ *FOa*/*FOb*/*FOb (*see screenshot below my aesteriks not showing with text formatting*)

**(Means profiles active suggesting the MAIN profile is active whenever ANY of the files is opened - much more flexible than what you had only 1 file.)**

[image: Linked profiles]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Now you can then link this Profile to the real Task you wish to perform.

The consequence of this is that you have created a **Profile with an Event which relates to 3 files not just one as before.**

Hope it helps, even to other scenarios where multiple actions relating to on event cannot be performed.